# Cancel Async Task with CancellationTokenSource from a button click not working

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, cancellationtokensource

What I need to do is able to cancel a task  that is running async. Task should be cancelled on cancel button click. I have done it with `CancellationTokenSource`. But  it is not working properly.

```cs
public class classA 
{
    CancellationTokenSource _tokenSource = null;

    public void OnCancelButtonClick()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Do you Really want to cancel upload");            
        _tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        _tokenSource.Cancel();
    }

    public async void UploadBtnClick(object param )
    {
        _tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var token = _tokenSource.Token;
        try
        {
            await Task.Run(() => UploadFunction(token));
        }
        catch(OperationCanceledException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

        }
        finally
        {
            _tokenSource.Dispose();
        }
    }

    public Task<bool> UploadFunction(CancellationToken token)
    {
        foreach
        {
            //code here

            if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            }
        }          
    }
}
```

I am calling `OnCancelButtonClick` from another function

```cs
public class classB 
{
    public void CancelUploadBtnExecute(object param)
    {
        FilesViewModel vm = new FilesViewModel();
        vm.OnCancelButtonClick(); 
    }
}
```

when I click on `OnCancelButtonClick` , `IsCancellationRequested` is `false`, but not reflected inside `UploadFunction` so the task won't stop.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are initializing new `CancellationTokenSource` in `OnCancelButtonClick()`.

Just remove this line from `OnCancelButtonClick()`

```
_tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
```

`UploadFunction` method is using token created from `CancellationTokenSource` in `UploadBtnClick` method.

Comment: System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

_tokenSource was null.

Comment: @developer Is the exception in OnCancelButtonClick method? If so then add check if(_tokenSource!=null).

Comment: yes exception in OnCancelButtonClick method

Comment: @developer When UploadBtnClick is called before OnCancelButtonClick then _tokenSource cannot be null, according to the code you share.

Comment: @developer Do you call UploadBtnClick from the same class as you call OnCancelButtonClick? If UploadBtnClick and OnCancelButtonClick are not called from the same class then you have to ensure that you call UploadBtnClick and OnCancelButtonClick on the same instance of classA.

Comment: popup have a cancel button which is on diff class.with the reference of A i am passing this popup button click event to class B ,where class B holds the logic of upload

Comment: @developer Could you share the popup and class B with us? It will help me and others to find the root cause. Thanks

Comment: public void CancelUploadBtnExecute(object param)
        {
          
           FilesViewModel vm = new FilesViewModel();
                vm.OnCancelButtonClick();
        }

Comment: @developer In classB.CancelUploadBtnExecute you are creating a new instance of FilesViewModel() but your class with popup is working with another instance of FilesViewModel. Use the same instance of FilesViewModel in class with popup and also with classB